# Two roots are not visible in the graph

Tags: plotting

When I graph the equation "dd i^2 + ee i l + ff l^2 - 0.55^2 = 0"[image], it only graphs for one root. However, for a value, two roots must be seen on the graph.
Thank you.
"
dd = 0.832606; ee = -1.87416; ff = 0.396505; ContourPlot[
dd i^2 + ee i l + ff l^2 - 0.55^2 == 0, {i, 0, 10}, {l, -1.5, 2.5}]"

Comment: Hello. Your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275904/plotting-an-equation-with-two-unknowns) was closed as being "easily found in the documentation". This question looks very similar. Please make a bigger effort to state a clear question and explain what you tried. You can edit your question and improve it.

Comment: For example, for i=0, it should give two roots as l value, but the 2nd root is not visible.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code,not the picture. `dd = 0.832606; ee = -1.87416; ff = 0.396505;
ContourPlot[
 dd i^2 + ee i l + ff l^2 - 0.55^2 == 0, {i, -10, 10}, {l, -10, 10}]`

Comment: Unfortunately, only one root appears.

Comment: For example, for l=0 there are roots i=-0.602758 and 0.602758, but only 0.602758 appears on the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `l==0`,we extend the plot range from `{i,0,10}`  to  `{i, -1, 10}` can see another roots.

```
Clear[dd, ee, ff];
dd = 0.832606; ee = -1.87416; ff = 0.396505;
ContourPlot[{dd i^2 + ee i l + ff l^2 - 0.55^2 == 0}, {i, -1, 
  10}, {l, -1.5, 2.5}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], Red], 
 GridLines -> {None, {0}}, GridLinesStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

- `i==0` there also two roots.

```
Clear[dd, ee, ff];
dd = 0.832606; ee = -1.87416; ff = 0.396505;
ContourPlot[{dd i^2 + ee i l + ff l^2 - 0.55^2 == 0}, {i, -1, 
  10}, {l, -1.5, 2.5}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &, #1 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], Red], 
 GridLines -> {{0}, None}, GridLinesStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.